# Python error importing dll files while py file import is successful

Tags: python-3.8

I have the setup as seen in the attached image:

[image]

Both the `pyd` and `functions.py` file are defined in the same folder yet the error is only at importing `pyd` file.

The error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named marketPriceMarcoPolo`

I am not sure what is going on.

Edit:

The pyd file was generated on Python 3.7 and is being used on a PC with Python 3.8 installed. Does it matter?

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...` - named what?

Comment: Are you actually using Python 3.7 64-bit?  That's the only version that will find it.

Comment: Can you specify the full name, that is everything up to `.pyd`?

Comment: Could you give a try to move the pyd file in the root folder? just to check path problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The pyd file was generated on Python 3.7 and is being used on a PC with Python 3.8 installed. Does it matter?

Yes, it matters.  It's in the name of the build (.cp37-amd_win64).  That means the extension is built for use with CPython 3.7 64-bit on Windows.

Extensions are linked to an explicit Python version. When you run your script on Python 3.8, it will look for `marketPriceMarcoPolo.cp38-win_amd64.pyd` instead.  Build it with the Python you intend to use it with.